AWS Amplify Gen 2, NextJS: How to Upload images from the NextJS backend API Route?
I'm using Amplify Gen 2 for my NextJS project.
I have been searching through all the docs but didn't find any example on how to upload files that comes to the NextJS backend API route. I tried the "uploadData" function available from "aws-amplify/storage", but it only works in the frontend implementation and not in the backend because it doesn't have the Authenticator wrapper information at the backend. So my request throws "Unauthorized, Access Denied" error.
Here is my example route.ts code that throws the error:
import { uploadData } from "aws-amplify/storage";

export async function POST(req: Request) {
  try {
    const formData = await req.formData();
    const image = formData.get("image") as File | null;
    const prisma = await db();

    if (image) {
      const filename = image.name;
      const result = prisma.$transaction(async (tx) => {
        const result = await prisma.image.create({
          data: {
            name: image.name,
          },
        });
        await uploadData({
          data: image,
          path: `images/${filename}`,
        });
        return result;
      });
      return Response.json(
        { message: "Image uploaded", result },
        { status: 200 }
      );
    }
    return Response.json({ message: "No image provided" }, { status: 400 });
  } catch (error) {
    console.error(error);
    return Response.json({ error: "Internal server error" }, { status: 500 });
  }
}

The reason why I need to do this on the backend and not in the frontend is because I need to update the database at the same time as a transaction. So if the image upload goes wrong for some connectivity issue, the database update gets rolled back.
Can someone please help me to figure out the code? How can I authenticate the AWS image upload connection at the NextJS backend?

I hope you resolved this, but it seems that the only option is to use function provided by the aws-sdk S3 client. Example with listing files:
import { S3 } from 'aws-sdk';

const s3 = new S3();

const bucketName = env.YOUR_STORAGE_BUCKET_NAME || '';
const prefix = '';

try {
    const params = {
        Bucket: bucketName,
        Prefix: prefix
    };

    const data = await s3.listObjectsV2(params).promise();
    const files = data.Contents?.map(item => item.Key) || [];
    console.log('Files:', files);

} catch (error) {
    console.error('Error listing files:', error);
}

